# Problema al girar pantalla con activity y/o fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

tengo un problema en la aplicación que estoy desarrollando, lo que pasa es que tengo un ViewPager en mi activityMain y en el fragment de inicio muestro información en un recycler view, mi aplicación trabajaba como esperaba hasta esta tarde, pero he regresado y le movido a algunas cosas, de lo que recuerdo agregué un landscape xml a mi fragment_home eliminé el archivo xml, ya que no me gusta, y después mi aplicación comenzó a lanzar excepciones como esta, es como si al girar se perdiera la referencia del fragment o algo por el estilo(Pierdo la referencia de el ArrayList en la clase del fragment, y eso es lo que me causa problemas):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.parlerfrench, PID: 25086
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.parlerfrench.fragments.fragment_home.onResume(fragment_home.java:55)
        at com.example.parlerfrench.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:223)
        at com.example.parlerfrench.MainActivity$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:202)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

Además al girar la pantalla me hace cosas que no debería hacer según el OnCreateView o el onResume de mi fragment, dejo el código de mi clase fragment:

```
public class fragment_home extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Texto> textos;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.loadingTextos);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Trae Textos de bd remota
        textos=MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().getArrayTextos();
        if(textos==null)
            textos=MainActivity.getmInstanceActivity().cargarTextos();
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), textos, getFragmentManager());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Refresca adapter con datos;

        if (textos!=null){
            adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), textos, getFragmentManager());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}
```

Las pantallas están así en portrait y landscape :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al girar la pantalla todo se pone en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté regresando con local history mi código a como estaba todo antes, intenté limpiando el proyecto, volviendo a crear el landscape(y lo volví a eliminar) y nada. Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme.

Por cualquier duda anexo mi case Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private static MainActivity activity_main;
    private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";
    private fragment_ajustes fragment_ajustes;
    private fragment_estadisticas fragment_estadisticas;
    private fragment_home fragment_home;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Texto> arrayTextos;

    private String URL_TEXTOS = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String ip = getString(R.string.ip);
        URL_TEXTOS=ip + "/parlerfrench/textoController.php?view=all";
        activity_main = this;

        //Primer inicio
        boolean muestra = getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext());
        if (muestra) {
            saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(getApplicationContext(), false);
        }

        //Modo oscuro
        String modo = getPreferenceString(getApplicationContext(), "dm");
        if (modo.equals("No existe") || modo.equals("sistema")) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        } else {
            if (modo.equals("oscuro")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            }
        }

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        fragment_ajustes = new fragment_ajustes();
        fragment_estadisticas = new fragment_estadisticas();
        fragment_home = new fragment_home();

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 0);

        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_estadisticas, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_stats));
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_home, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_home));
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(fragment_ajustes, getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_settings));
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_bar_chart);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_voice);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_settings);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = tabLayout.getTabAt(position).getOrCreateBadge();
                badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        //Tab de home seleccionada
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(1));

    }

    public void setBadge(int tabIndex, int num) {
        BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = tabLayout.getTabAt(tabIndex).getOrCreateBadge();
        //Pone un número si lleva uno diferente a 0
        if (num != 0)
            badgeDrawable.setNumber(num);
        badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> fragmentsTitle = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
            super(fm, behavior);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            fragments.add(fragment);
            fragmentsTitle.add(title);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentsTitle.get(position);
        }

    }

    public String getPreferenceString(Context context, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String dato = preferences.getString(nombre, "No existe");
        return dato;
    }

    public void setPreferenceString(Context context, String dato, String nombre) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(nombre, dato);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean("primerInicio", true);
    }

    public void saveValuePreferencePrimerInicio(Context context, Boolean mostrar) {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("primerInicio", mostrar);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public ArrayList cargarTextos() {
        arrayTextos=new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_TEXTOS, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = response;
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("textos");
                            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                JSONObject object=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Texto texto=new Texto(object.getString("texto"),
                                        object.getString("autor"),object.getString("origen"), object.getString("nivel"));
                                arrayTextos.add(texto);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            fragment_home.stopLoading();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("error", "error trycatch: "+response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error tyrcatch: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        //Se refresca el fragment home
                        fragment_home.onResume();
                    }
                },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                fragment_home.stopLoading();
                                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                    Log.e("Error", "Error de conexion: " + error.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error de conexión! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Register errorResponse! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("error", error.toString());
                            }
                        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                5000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        VolleySingleton.getInstanceVolley(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

        return arrayTextos;

    }


    public static MainActivity getmInstanceActivity() {
        return activity_main;
    }

    public  ArrayList<Texto> getArrayTextos(){
        return arrayTextos;
    }
```

Y mi xml del fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.fragment_home">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingTextos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ProgressBar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opciòn para evitar este problema es que definas dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` en la Activity que carga el fragment

```
<activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    .../>
        ...
</activity>
```

Con esto evitarìas se destruya la Activity y por ende el Fragment.

---

Con respecto a que pierdes la referencia de la vista en `onResume()` te sugiero revises si tienes otro layout fragment_home.xml que se cargue en otra orientaciòn puede suceder que el progressbar no se encuentre ahì por esa razòn se provocarìa un NullPointerException.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.loadingTextos);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Trae Textos de bd remota
        ...
        ...
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
           ...
           ...
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Soluciona temporalmente el problema, pero sería forzar a no tener el error, pero tienes idea de a qué se deba el problema o qué es lo que puedo revisar para detectar el problema?, porque en los otros 2 fragments trabaja normal sólo es ese en el que tengo problemas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: revisa por favor si tienes otro archivo fragment_home.xml que se cargue en otra orientacion

Comment: Revisé y sólo están los 2 que deberían estar en sus respectivas carpetas(dejé el landscape)

Comment: ok, tener 2 layouts diferentes es por si deseas presentar un layout con alguna diferencia en otra orientación, pero en algunas cosas no es necesario más que solo uno, hubieras revisado si ambos en realidad tenían el progressBar con el id loadingTextos